# Sending message through java mail

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail, mime-message, mime-mail

Hello i am able to send a mail from my web application. But the problem here is am able to send only one line of message ie

I want to send a message saying:

Your username is : xxxx
Your PassWord is: xxx

```
     Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("xxx@gmail.com"));
                    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        InternetAddress.parse(Class.email));
                    message.setSubject("Registration Confirmation with SK Business Group");
                    message.setContent("<h1>Congratulations on successfully registering with us</h1><h2>Your user name is:</h2>" +Class.uname ,  
                            "text/html");
message.setContent("<h2>Your password is:</h2>" +Class.pass ,  
                            "text/html");

                    Transport.send(message);
```

But when the mail reaches the recipient only username is displayed...

I want both username and password to be displayed. Some one please help me resolving this..Thanks in advance.

**Note :
Uname and pass are static variables of a class which is got by its classname.**

Comment: why dont you just try simple HTML code for next line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting the content twice, add both lines in the same call to `setContent`:

```
message.setContent("<h1>Congratulations on successfully registering with us</h1>"
    + "<h2>Your user name is:</h2>" +ApproveDAO.uname
    + "<h2>Your password is:</h2>" +ApproveDAO.pass, "text/html");
```

Comment: how to bold the variable value can u please tell me?? like whatever +ApproveDAO.uname returns should be boldfaced.. How to do this??

Comment: Your string should be like this: `"<h1>Congratulations on successfully registering with us</h1><h2>Your user name is:</h2><b>" + ApproveDAO.uname + "</b><h2>Your password is:</h2><b>" +ApproveDAO.pass + "</b>"

Comment: No only color is getting changed font remains the same.... i mean its not boldfaced

Comment: Your browser is not rendering HTML correctly; also, the tags h1 and h2 are for titles, not for bolding, try this string (playing with values for sizes in style): `"<p style='font-size:18px;'>Congratulations on successfully registering with us</p><p style='font-size:16px;'>Your user name is: <b>" + ApproveDAO.uname + "</b></p><p style='font-size:16px;'>Your password is: <b>" +ApproveDAO.pass + "</b></p>"`

Comment: You have to copy the double quotes as well